# Symbols after value of variable

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a code like:

```
For i = 1 To fRow
    ali = wbTarget.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value

    For j = 1 To fRow
        If nwb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value = ali
```

what exactly happens is:

1. We give a value for variable "ali" that is in column 14.
2. We compare that variable with another cell

Issue is:

- "ali" value can be let's say 85020, but the value we compare it with can be 850200. As you see there is 1 additional zero behind. I want them to be matched. How can I perform ali* to the variable?

Thank You very much!

Comment: does every compare value have a digit too much?

Comment: no, not always, let's say 45895 will match completely. Only values with 0 in the end won't match

Comment: and yes, every value is a digit

Comment: every time when the last digit is 0 it has to be deleted?

Comment: at the moment "nwb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value" and ali don't match, because of that additional 0. how can i say that variable "ali" with anything behind it, has to matched?
lets say 525* = 52565

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
If nwb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value = ali
```

To

```
If nwb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value = ali Or _
nwb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value Like ali & "*" Then
```